# Javascript & Soundcloud Widget: How to load new track into SC Widget iFrame (via URL)

Tags: javascript, widget, soundcloud

I’ve seen different web apps like Playmoss, Whyd, and Songdrop etc. that, I believe, HAVE to utilize the Soundcloud Embedded Widget in order to produce the functionality of playing multiple tracks, in sucession, not apart of a set/(playlist). Currently I am having issues reproducing this functionality with the following library, so I decided to attempt to write my own:

https://github.com/eric-robinson/SCLPlayer

I am very new to writing javascript, but my below code, will load a first track, and play it once hitting the “ready” bind. Once hitting the “finish” bind, It will then jump to the loadNextTrack() function and load the next tracks URL, into the src of the widget’s iFrame. After that, it doesn’t ever hit the original “ready” bind, which would then begin playback.

So to clear things up, playback doesn’t begin for the second track.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">

         var SCLPlayer = {
            isPlayerLoaded : false,
            isPlayerFullLoaded : false,
            needsFirstTrackSkip : true,
            isPaused: true,

            scPlayer : function() {
                widgetContainer = document.getElementById('sc');
                widget = SC.Widget(widgetContainer);
                return widget;
            },

            loadNextTrack : function() {
                var ifr = document.getElementById('sc');
                ifr.src = 'http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/231758952';

                console.log ('Loading Next Track');

                SCLPlayer.scPlayer().bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {

                    console.log ('Player is Ready, next Track');

                    SCLPlayer.scPlayer().play();
                });
            }
        };

        $( '#sc' ).ready(function() {
            SCLPlayer.scPlayer().bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
                SCLPlayer.isPlayerLoaded = true;
                //window.location = 'sclplayer://didLoad';

                console.log ('Player is Ready');
                SCLPlayer.scPlayer().play();
            });

            SCLPlayer.scPlayer().bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
                SCLPlayer.isPaused = false;
                //window.location = 'sclplayer://didPlay';

                console.log ('Player did Play');
            });

            SCLPlayer.scPlayer().bind(SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE, function() {
                SCLPlayer.isPaused = true;
                //window.location = 'sclplayer://didPause';

                console.log ('Player did Pause');
            });

            SCLPlayer.scPlayer().bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function() {
                SCLPlayer.isPaused = true;
                //window.location = 'sclplayer://didFinish';

                console.log ('Player did Finish');

                SCLPlayer.loadNextTrack();
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <iframe id = "sc" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/226183306"></iframe>
</body>
```

The whole point of me writing this Javascript is so that I can then use a Swift to Javascript bridge in my iOS app to then control the loading of tracks into the embedded players. For some reason over a slower connection, the next track doesn't always load into the player, using the "bridge". I hope to provide the nextTrackURL to the javascript side of things before the currentTrack finishes, so that the bridge conveys nothing and the Javascript handles new track loading, solely on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the load function to specify the url for the new track

From the soundcloud Widget API docs:

load(url, options) — reloads the iframe element with a new widget specified by the url. All previously added event listeners will continue working. options is an object which allows you to define all possible widget parameters as well as a callback function which will be executed as soon as new widget is ready. See below for detailed list of widget parameters.

```
var url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/";
var options = [];
// if a track 
url += "tracks/";
// if a playlist
url += "playlists/"
// append the id of the track / playlist to the url
url += id;
// set any options you want for the player
options.show_artwork = false;
options.liking = false;
options.auto_play = true;

widget.load(url, options, OPTIONAL_CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
```

Edited to show binding...

The bind code is called once, after the widget is initially loaded.

The ready event is only called once, when the widget is initially loaded, it is not called for each subsequent call using load().

```
try {
  widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, 
  function finishedPlaying() { 
     // your code / function call 
    }
  );
  widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE, 
  function paused() { 
     // your code / function call 
    }
  );
  widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, 
  function playing() { 
     // your code / function call 
     widget.getCurrentSound(function scCurrentSound(sound) {
        // this also binds getCurrent sound which is called
        // each time a new sound is loaded
      });
    }
  );
  widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, 
  function position(pos) { 
     // your code / function call 
    }
  );
  widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.SEEK, 
  function seek(pos) { 
     // your code / function call 
    }
  );
  widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, 
  function ready() { 
     // your code / function call 
    }
  );
} catch(e) {
 // exception handler code
}
```

Comment: Okay, THANK YOU for the load function, that works! It loads the next track, now the only issue I am having is that previously added event listeners are not being called after the load of the next track. My loadNextTrack function contains the code you provided above.